# how to find out Java Program environment used

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm using eclipse for a java program that I was just handed . I was wondering if there is a way to find out what environment like libraries, Jars , or references that were used for this java program. It was built in '02, and its almost older than me. Please help anyone

Comment: Right click the project => Properties => Java Build Path

Comment: I'm assuming you were given the source code, and not a jar file.  Put the source code in Eclipse using Java 7 or 8.  Eclipse will tell you what's missing.  If you're missing entire Java classes, Google them to see what external library they belong to.

Comment: The java build path helped me a lot. It's running in sdk 1.3 for windows.
thank you both, I have a warning for a namespace called java.awt.event.* . Do I need to download something for this ? I'm not too familiar with java . I'm more familiar with .NET .

Comment: Download a modern Java version (version 8 or 7), install it & then change the SDK inside the Eclipse project from 1.3 to the newly installed one. The program will be probably 100s of times faster. Java is also much more backwards-compatible than .NET so the old code should still run fine.